# Responsive rollover megamenu for bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a responsive megamenu for bootstrap 3, I found the one below
http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

and applied it to my build here
http://think.darkstarmedia.net

The big problem with it is that when on a desktop, the menu wont rollover, you need to click it open.

So my question is 2 part

1. Can we make it open on rollover when on a desktop?
2. or can someone recommend a bootstrap 3  megamenu which will do what I need?

All the ones I find are only on Click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it with JS and includes a media query condition to only enable the `hover` function on a viewport higher then 800px.

Working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elektriheart/sz2842vq/)

```
//NAV Dropdown Hover
$(function() {

  if ($(window).width() > 800) {

    $(".dropdown").hover(

      function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
      },

      function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome! If the solution worked please check it as answered so others can benefit from it.

Comment: There is no way to mark your response as the answer, it will only allow me to post the answer

Comment: Look at this just in case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work